# How to send a 'conversationUpdate' to Microsoft Teams from bot manually?

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I have a bot written with the help of bot `framework v4`. The bot is integrated with Microsoft Teams. I want to send a welcome message to the user when the user installed the bot and joins the 1:1 conversation. In Teams the `conversationUpdate` is fired exactly once (this is when the suer joins the 1:1 conversation) and then never again for that user. My idea was to write a function that is triggered by a chat message to send the `updateConversation` activity manually to debug the welcome message.

I failed so far and got a

> BadArgument: Unknown activity type exception.

I have tried using the [Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Teams](https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams) nuget using the `ConnectorClient` to send the `conversationUpdate` activity to the conversation.

Also I set up a console application and tried using the `v3/directline/conversations/{conversationId}/activities` and got a `Forbidden` error.

```
private async Task SendConversationUpdateToTeamsAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cToken = default)
{
    var connectorClient = turnContext.TurnState.Get<IConnectorClient>();

    var conversationUpdateMessage = new Activity
    {
        Type = ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate,
        Id = turnContext.Activity.Id,
        ServiceUrl = turnContext.Activity.ServiceUrl,
        From = turnContext.Activity.From,
        Recipient = turnContext.Activity.Recipient,
        Conversation = turnContext.Activity.Conversation,
        ChannelData = turnContext.Activity.ChannelData,
        ChannelId = turnContext.Activity.ChannelId,
        Timestamp = turnContext.Activity.Timestamp,
        MembersAdded = new List<ChannelAccount>
        {
            turnContext.Activity.From,
            turnContext.Activity.Recipient
        },
    };

    var result = await connectorClient.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(conversationUpdateMessage, cToken);
}
```

I expect that sending a `conversationUpdate` manually to debug the behavior in Teams works. Creating new users in the office portal and installing the bot for them to debug the `conversationUpdate` behavior is no option for me, because it is to time consuming. If there is another workaround to trigger the `conversationUpdate` in Teams please let me know.

Comment: Here is how you can [synthesize a fake event conversation update event](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-csharp/blob/1003c10c6b92e661e6e1f900c5e2434bb59a4afe/template-bot-master-csharp/src/controllers/MessagesController.cs#L234) and simulate the bot receiving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of a way to force a `ConversationUpdate` to be sent in the way you're attempting to. Instead, I'd just throw something like this in `OnMessageAsync()`:

```cs
if (turnContext.Activity.Text == "fakeConversationUpdate")
{
    var fakeTurnContext = new TurnContext(turnContext.Adapter, MessageFactory.Text(string.Empty));
    fakeTurnContext.Activity.AsConversationUpdateActivity();
    fakeTurnContext.Activity.Type = ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate;
    fakeTurnContext.Activity.MembersAdded = new List<ChannelAccount>()
    {
        new ChannelAccount()
        {
            Id = "fakeUserId",
            Name = "fakeUserName"
        }
    };
    await OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync(new DelegatingTurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity>(fakeTurnContext), cancellationToken);

}
```

Then to debug, you just write "fakeConversationUpdate" (which you can change/customize) to the bot in chat and it will send your `fakeTurnContext` (which you can change/customize) through `OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync()`

Comment: Thanks! That solved it. One small adjustment though. I had to wrap the ```fakeTurnContext``` with a ```DelegatingTurnContext``` otherwise the cast to ```ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity>``` returns ```null```.