# Sending proactive messages to ms teams from azure deployed bot

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I've already deployed the bot to azure, when connecting to the ms team channel in azure, i'm able to ping the bot and receive messages which is good.
I've also added a proactive messaging in the bot where a message will be triggered every one minute in the channel.

[image: Connecting to MS Teams]

Its working in the emulator, however its not working in webchat and MS teams:
The notifier controller is not being triggered.

Could you please help me on that?
I've uploaded the code in GITHUB:
https://github.com/nivinsunathree/Botv4.git

```
public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);


    System.Timers.Timer checkForTime = new System.Timers.Timer(interval60Minutes);
    checkForTime.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(checkForTime_Elapsed);
    checkForTime.Enabled = true;


    // Save any state changes that might have occured during the turn.
    await _conversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
    await _userState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
}

void checkForTime_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    bool timeIsReady = true;
    if (timeIsReady == true)
    {
        var url = "http://localhost:3978/api/notify";

        try
        {
            Process.Start(url);
        }
        catch
        {
            // hack because of this: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10361
            if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
            {
                url = url.Replace("&", "^&");
                Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", $"/c start {url}") { CreateNoWindow = false });
            }
            else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
            {
                Process.Start("xdg-open", url);
            }
            else if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX))
            {
                Process.Start("open", url);
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After one minute, it should trigger below message in the channel:

```
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Hello!" + Environment.NewLine + $"Trust you are well" + Environment.NewLine + $"Hope that you are having a good day" + Environment.NewLine + $"We are contacting you concerning lea access requests" + Environment.NewLine + $"Could you please review the following tasks if any and add the required information!"), cancellationToken);
//await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Please type ok to continue!"), cancellationToken);
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Could you please click on the below button to continue?"));

var card = new HeroCard
{
    //Text = "Could you please click on the below button to continue?",
    Buttons = new List<CardAction>
        {
            new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, title: "lea access request", value: "lea access request"),
        },
};
var reply = MessageFactory.Attachment(card.ToAttachment());
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
```

Answer (score 2):

I mentioned this via email, but I'll repost it here for others:

Your proactive messaging works in Emulator but not in Teams because you only add a `ConversationReference` in `EchoBot.OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync`.

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55517906/how-do-i-send-a-11-welcome-message/55525014#55525014), Teams only sends a ConversationUpdate when the bot is installed or a user speaks with the bot the FIRST time EVER. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57304988/how-to-send-a-conversationupdate-to-microsoft-teams-from-bot-manually/57315460#57315460) is a way you can test it.

Comment: i've added the conversation reference to the onmessageasync.
   protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            AddConversationReference(turnContext.Activity as Activity);
            System.Timers.Timer checkForTime = new System.Timers.Timer(interval60Minutes);
            checkForTime.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(checkForTime_Elapsed);
            checkForTime.Enabled = true;
Is it because my bot is not being used for the first time on teams?

Comment: Is it possible to get someone for a screensharing for these issues.
I'm stuck with it since the last one week as you know?
Thank you