# Teams Bot SDK fails to get team info using channel conversationUpdate reference

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have a conversationUpdate event for a channel, that I'm using as the `conversationReference` in the following code snippet. For some reason, when I try to run this code, I get an error saying "This method is only valid within the scope of a MS Teams Team." even though as far as I can tell, the event I've provided *is* in the scope of a team (as further proof, `conversation.conversationType` is `channel`). Conversely, I am able to call `TeamsInfo.getPagedMembers()` successfully, which I would expect to fail if I weren't in a team scope.

```
const proactiveChannelHandler = async (turnContext) => {
  try {
    const teamDetails = await TeamsInfo.getTeamDetails(turnContext);
    if (teamDetails) {
      await turnContext.sendActivity(`The group ID is: ${teamDetails.aadGroupId}`);
    } else {
      await turnContext.sendActivity('This message did not come from a channel in a team.');
    }
  } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
  }
}

adapter.continueConversation(conversationReference, proactiveChannelHandler);
```

Comment: Have you tried the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57304988/how-to-send-a-conversationupdate-to-microsoft-teams-from-bot-manually) sample?

Comment: @Dev Unless I'm missing something, this seems unrelated.

Comment: Can we have call to discuss this please forward this issue at microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue was that I was missing the required second argument for the team ID.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully obtain a list of channels using the below example:

```
        private static async Task ListChannelsAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var channels = await TeamsInfo.GetTeamChannelsAsync(turnContext, null, cancellationToken);

            foreach (var channel in channels)
            {
                if (channel.Name == null)
                    channel.Name = "General";
            }

            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Channels list: {string.Join(", ", channels.Select(c => c.Name).ToArray())}"), cancellationToken);
        }
```